# Automatically graph chart c# .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, charts

Is it possible to automatically create a chart for a given result of a query?

For example, let's say that I have a select query that returns 3 rows (will always return something different based on status of active or not.)  Is it possible to graph out those 3 rows individually on pageload without predefining those charts?

I'm not looking for any code, just a step in the right direction.  I'm assuming that its possible, but more involved and more coding is needed to accomplish this.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnLoad="Chart2_Load">
             <Series>
                 <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" XValueMember="insert_date" YValueMembers="recs_last_minute">
                 </asp:Series>
             </Series>
             <ChartAreas>
                 <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                 </asp:ChartArea>
             </ChartAreas>
         </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: I'm using visual studios community 2015 gui to drag and drop these charts.

Comment: You could try adding all those results to a `list`, and then use a `foreach` statement to show each item in that list into a row.

Comment: Seems like a step in the right direction, but it sounds like you are referring to gridview.  I want to be able to be able to display a control chart for each query result.  Would this still apply?  Sorry, if i'm not making sense.

Comment: Perhaps provide some example code to show the chart already? From there it should be fairly easy to make it display a chart for each query result.

Answer (score 0):

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = m_objGridSetting.StartPoint_X;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = m_objGridSetting.Specing_Dx;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval =  m_objGridSetting.Specing_Dx;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = m_objGridSetting.Startpoint_Y;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = m_objGridSetting.Specing_Dy;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = m_objGridSetting.Specing_Dy;
        m_objGraphRoot.lstAxis.Sort();
        chart1.DataSource = m_objGraphRoot.lstAxis;
        chart1.DataBind();
```

// here is codeing sample

Comment: It's best to describe what the problem is and how your code solves it.